# PHP mysqli case sensitive query but not when ran in phpmyadmin

Tags: php

I'm having a nightmare with my PHP mysqli query. I've made a php page with a get request from the url for the software name. Then when I try and use this in a mysqli query it's running the query as case sensitive but when the command is run in phpmyadmin it runs as case insensitive (which is what I want). 
The query which works in phpmyadmin:

```
`SELECT * FROM seinventory WHERE software LIKE '%$xampp%'`
```

returns the same result as

```
`SELECT * FROM seinventory WHERE software LIKE '%$XAMPP%'`
```

(in the database the text field has it as XAMPP, and the encoding of the column is set to utf8_general_ci)

**my php code:**

```
$softwareName = $_GET['soft'];
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `seinventory` WHERE software LIKE '%$softwareName%'");
```

It only returns the result when the url has XAMPP in capitals but running the url with `soft=xampp` returns nothing.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the encoding on the `GET request`, it comes up as ASCII and when I try and convert it to **UTF8** with `mb_convert_encoding` nothing changes.

Comment: No, this can’t be about the encoding of your parameter - all characters in `xampp` are on the same code points in ASCII, and UTF-8. The representation of that value in both encodings is _exactly_ the same.

Comment: please add table for a reference.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it, further down in my code I had strpos to compare $softwareName to some values before it created the table but strpos is case sensitive so the two values didnt match ive changed it to stripos and its all working,